# Rails 2 : add double confirm dialogs

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, form-submit

I'm currently trying to implement a double confirm dialog on a submit_tag.

I mean, suppose you want to delete a Post and you want a `JavaScript` alert to popup confirming your choice. You would do it with:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', @post, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

When user clicks, an alert pops up asking confirmation.

Now, I want to really be sure the user wants to delete the post, so I would like to have another alert popup.

Basically: 
`user clicks -> first popup "Are you sure?" -> second popup -> "Are you really sure?"`

I'm using jQuery and discarded Prototype.

Answer (score 3):

I guess a simple way would be to have a jQuery function which gets called when you click the link. Something like:

```
function double_confirm() {
  var confirm1 = confirm('Are you sure?');
  if (confirm1 === true) {
    return confirm('Are you really sure?');
  }
  return false;
}
```

As a side note, I don't think this is really good behaviour. It's going to get really annoying for the user having to confirm everything twice. Likelihood is that they'll become accustomed to clicking ok twice so this won't really prevent accidental deletion. A more user-friendly way might be to allow undo. You could trying using paper_trail: https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail (using the rails2 branch).

Comment: Could you elaborate? What doesn't work? https://gist.github.com/1853212 works for me in Chrome.